# Celery --pool=threads -- what does this do and how do I use it properly?

Tags: python, multithreading, celery

I'm hitting a segfault error while running a task using Celery. After looking up the issue, it seems others are solving similar issues by starting celery with `--pool=threads`.

When I try passing `--pool=threads` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'threads'`

I don't believe this is the same as the `thread` module which would throw the error of `No module named 'thread'` instead.

How do I start using threads and what does it do?

The documentation regarding `--pool=threads` in the Celery site is very sparse. Searching for "--pool" will return nothing substantial, other than things related to billiard

Comment: threads pool is removed since celery 4.

Comment: Where did you get that information? - Check the 4.4.0 changelog please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use threads as your execution pool, you can choose between eventlet an gevent.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-p

You need to `pip install` eventlet/gevent to make it work.

Comment: This is not entirely true, as Celery 4.4.0 has "thread" concurrency type.

Comment: Down-voted as there's now `--pool=threads`.

Answer (score 7):

Just-released Celery 4.4.0 adds `--pool thread` to the concurrency list.

You can read more at [Celery 4.4 Changelogs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/history/whatsnew-4.4.html?highlight=pool%20threads#threaded-tasks-pool):

> Threaded Tasks Pool

> We reintroduced a threaded task pool using
> concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor.

> The previous threaded task pool was experimental. In addition it was based on the threadpool package which is obsolete.

> You can use the new threaded task pool by setting worker_pool to ‘threads` or by passing –pool threads to the celery worker command.

Now you can use threads instead of processes for pooling.

```
celery worker -A your_application --pool threads --loginfo=INFO
```

Comment: Updated change log link https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/history/whatsnew-4.4.html?highlight=pool%20threads#threaded-tasks-pool